# How do I avoid an uninitialized value?

Tags: perl

I use this `scrub` function to clean up output from other functions.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Data::Dumper;

my %h = (
    a => 1,
    b => 1
    );

print scrub($h{c});

sub scrub {
    my $a = shift;

    return ($a eq '' or $a eq '~' or not defined $a) ? -1 : $a;
}
```

The problem occurs when I also would like to handle the case, where the key in a hash doesn't exist, which is shown in the example with `scrub($h{c})`.

What change should be make to `scrub` so it can handle this case?

Comment: `The problem occurs now when I would like to should also be able to handle the case` ?

Comment: It is better to avoid using `$a` as a variable name.

Comment: yes, good point about $a. It and $b have special meaning in sort(), so should be avoided for use as general-purpose variables.  Also they're not meaningful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're checking whether `$a eq ''` before checking whether it's defined, hence the warning "Use of uninitialized value in string eq". Simply change the order of things in the conditional:

```
return (!defined($a) or $a eq '' or $a eq '~') ? -1 : $a;
```

As soon as anything in the chain of 'or's matches, Perl will stop processing the conditional, thus avoiding the erroneous attempt to compare undef to a string.

Comment: The defined-or is also handy for this. $a //= '' sets $a to '' if it isn't currently defined. Then you don't need to worry about subsequent definedness.

Comment: The term is *[short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)*.

Answer (score -1):

In `scrub` it is too late to check, if the hash has an entry for key `key`. `scrub()` only sees a scalar, which is `undef`, if the hash key does not exist. But a hash could have an entry with the value `undef` also, like this:

```
my %h = (
 a => 1,
 b => 1,
 c => undef
);
```

So I suggest to check for hash entries with the [`exists`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exists.html) function.

Comment: So, you are not interested in checking if a hash entry exists. I thought you were. It is _not_ the same as checking for 'definedness' of a value. If you read from a hash with a non existent key, you get `undef`. But $h{c} from my example would also give `undef`, although the key 'c' exists. So these cases cannot be distinguished. If something is not correct, please state what.